# React class is not defined (text/babel)

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

I have commentBox.jsx file, with following code:

```jsx
var CommentBox = React.createClass( {
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

In index.html, I want to render this component:

```jsx
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/babel" src="scripts/commentBox.jsx"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox />, document.getElementById( 'content' ) );
</script>
```

But I'm getting error: "CommentBox is not defined"; Why this is not working?
If I will place all code in one file(commentBox.js) - it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `var CommentBox;` in its own script block above the other two. The scope of your variables is not shared between your script imports.

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
  var CommentBox;
</script>
<script type="text/babel" src="scripts/commentBox.jsx"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox />, document.getElementById( 'content' ) );
</script>
```

You can also remove the `var` from your `jsx` file.

Comment: This worked for me.  Be sure to use `<script>`, not `<script type="text/babel">`.

Answer (score 0):

CommentBox is not declared. If you want it that way, then your codes should go like this:

```jsx
<script type="text/babel">
var CommentBox = React.createClass( {
  render: function () {
  return (
    <div className="commentBox">
          <h1>Comments</h1>
    </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox />, document.getElementById( 'content' ) );

</script>
```

Comment: What you can say about ReactDom object in this code? Is it not declared to?

Comment: The ReactDom is the library used to render the component to the DOM and should be imported to the code but the component itself such as CommentBox is also not defined.

Comment: It is wrong answer)) CommentBox I added before the call of ReactDOM.render. It must be exists in global scope of window object

Comment: I'm also having this issue, I can only get it to work when the definition is in the same script tags as the usage.